# Web view back button problem in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hai friends,
I implemented web view in one of my activity, when i am trying to go to previous activity(by clicking the back button)

whole application is terminating.

In the back button

I have written the following code to close the activity..

```
Intent in=new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, in);
        finish();
```

Thanks,
Bhargav.

Comment: To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, accepts the good answers of your questions

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```