# Webview scale is changed in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have 4 tabs at top of my application. One tab opens a Url but clicking on the link in that page hides the tabBar which is not required.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news);
        WebView bpBrowser=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        bpBrowser.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");         
}
```

For any help Thanks

Comment: It will open browser and show contents??

Comment: Ya it shows some content but my tabbar is not visible when i surf on some other page.

Comment: You need to Override Url it will solve :)

Comment: something like this `bpBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

Comment: I applied but when i want to go back to my previous page it finishes my whole application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5863780/1166537 Check tat link it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override url `bpBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5863780/1166537)  for more information about overriding back button in `WebView`